# Nginx supervisord configuration

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I have a `supervisord` server running on `localhost:9001`.
I am trying to serve it at `localhost/supervisord`.

The `nginx` config is like this:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
#daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # MIME / Charset
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    charset utf-8;

    # Logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Other params
    server_tokens off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    sendfile on;

    upstream supervisord {
        server localhost:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
          client_max_body_size 4G;
          keepalive_timeout 5;

        location ^~ /stylesheets {
          alias  /Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/ui/stylesheets;
          access_log off;
        }

        location ^~ /images {
          alias  /Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/ui/images;
          access_log off;
        }

        location /supervisord {
            # Set client IP / Proxy IP
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

            # Set host header
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://supervisord/;
        }
    }
}
```

Before adding `^~ /images` and `^~ /stylesheets` locations the page was returning a `502 Bad Gateway`.

With the above config I am able to access `localhost/supervisord` but the CSS is missing on the page.

I see the css / images are loaded correctly in the browser:

[image: Assets loaded]

But I see an error message in the browser console and it seems to be the culprit:

[image: Stylesheet not loaded]

The mimetype in the browser for `localhost/stylesheets/supervisor.css` it shows as `octet-stream` instead of `text/css`.

The mimetype in the browser for `localhost:9001/stylesheets/supervisor.css` it shows as the correct `text/css`.

**How can I fix this error ?**

I thought about dynamically rewriting the mimetype for static files, but I am not an expert in `nginx` and have no idea how to do that from `nginx` config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really interesting such an obvious function like putting web interfaces behind transparent reverse proxy is not that straightforward to configure as it should be.

Anyway this is what I do to get reverse proxy working with applications where root can't be modified, like supervisor:

```
           location /supervisor {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
           }

           location / {

            if ($http_referer ~ "^.*/supervisor"){
              return 301 /supervisor/$request_uri;
            }
          }
```

Application-side requests will hit the main end-point but then NginX will re-direct them to the /supervisor EP

This works in most cases but not always.The following supervisor's web functions will fail:

1. getting action confirmation - you can start / stop services but the result page will fail to load; just go to the /supervisor EP to check the result
2. live tail does not work; however there is a log display with manual refresh which works under the link with the program name.

Anyway this partial support is good engough for me and you may find it also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working simply with this:

```
upstream supervisor {
  server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}

server {
  # ... 

  location /supervisor/ {
    proxy_pass  http://supervisor/;
  }
}
```

Even worked in the browser with and without ending slash in url (ie both http://example.com/supervisor and http://example.com/supervisor/ worked).
This was a must for me!